# Deploying .NET application on XP machine with SQLite db

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, sqlite

I came across this problem. SQLite db is visible from my program to the DataGrid and DataSet. The problem occurs in the first reference of a query which relies on EntitiyFramework 5.0 In this case the database is not available, and returned the following error:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while
>   executing the command  definition. See the inner exception for
>   details. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException:  SQL logic error or
>   missing database

My app.config is has the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
     <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
        <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
      </DbProviderFactories>
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbConnectionString" connectionString="data source=db.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
    <add name="MyApp.My.MySettings.dbConnectionString" connectionString="&quot;data source=db.sqlite&quot; providerName=&quot;System.Data.SQLite&quot;" />

 <add name="dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data source=db.sqlite&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**how do I set the database so for EF is always available?**

Answer (score 0):

System.Data.Sqlite does not support creating databases for the entity framework.  You need to add the SQLite database to the project